# To perform POST http request by an dialog component

Tags: angular, angular6, angular-services

I have component called `list` which will display some title names from an **api** like this:

[image]

As shown in image, I have `fab-button` called **Add**. On clicking this fab-button. I am calling an dialog window (component name is add-customer). like this:

[image]

Now from this dialog window i want to fill input fields(i,e title and description) of the form and i want post it server, Means i want send `http POST` request on clicking 
**SAVE** button.

I am able call api using **GET** method.But for **POST** method,I am unable to do.

[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/list-examples-mine-nqjhhz?file=app/add-customer/add-customer.component.ts)

In `add-customer.ts` i passing the values from the form to an function called **postCustomer**

I can see in this in the console:

[image]

I just want to know that how can assign this **postCustomer** function to POST method in `service.ts` file.

I am trying like this:

```
   public postCustomer(): Promise<IContact[]> {
    const apiUrl: string = 'api.........';

    return this.http.post<IContact[]>(apiUrl).toPromise();
  }
```

Comment: And where is the code for the `POST`?

Comment: Note that you don't have to specify the `public` keyword for all methods and variables.

Comment: You should be able to call `HttpClient#post` to create a POST method.

Comment: Let me udpdate the `stackblitz`

Comment: 1. Better use observable instead of promise. You have to pass to `putContactList` the data yout get to the form after marking it as dirty.

Comment: Please see the updated **DEMO**, From watching an example i have tried up to here, I am stuck here..:) Need help.

Comment: I have called the `GET` and `POST` methods inside an file called `service.ts`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### For POST method:

For `POST` methods you have a body to send, change your service to :

```
  public postCustomer(data): Promise<IContact[]> {
    const apiUrl: string = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts';

    return this.http.post<IContact[]>(apiUrl, data).toPromise();
  }
```

Then in your `AddCustomerComponent` refactor your method `onAddCustomer()` to:

```
 public onAddCustomer(): void {
    this.markAsDirty(this.addCusForm);
    this.postCustomer=this.addCusForm.value;
    console.log(this.postCustomer);
    this.service.postCustomer(this.postCustomer).then(
      (response)=> {
          console.log('POST called', response);

      }
    )
  }
```

Do not forget to import your `Service` in the same component:

```
import {Service} from '../service';
```

And inject it in the `constructor`:

```
constructor(private fb: FormBuilder, private service: Service) { }
```

---

**NOTE:** I do not get why you're using **`Promises`** over **`Observables`**, you have to change them for more consistency and powerful operators.

Comment: Thanks for your answer guidance too..:)

Comment: I am getting this warning in `service.ts` file : **[ts] Expected 2-3 arguments, but got 1.**

Comment: Actually the warning is showing on the existing **stackblitz DEMO** only, please see once..:)

Comment: Means in `service.ts` file.

Comment: @PrashanthGH That is already mentioned in my answer .. (you have a body to send ... )